# Missing headers in csv output file (python)

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x, standard-library

I am trying to output a csv file, but the problem is, the headers are gone, and I tried looking at my code line by line but I don't know what's wrong with my code..

My sample data is :
ABC.csv (assuming there are multiple data in it so I also add the code on how to remove it)

```
KeyID,GeneralID
145258,KL456
145259,BG486
145260,HJ789
145261,KL456
145259,BG486
145259,BG486
```

My code:

```
import csv
import fileinput
from collections import Counter

file_path_1 = "ABC.csv"

key_id = []
general_id = []
total_general_id = []

with open(file_path_1, 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    lines = [line for line in reader]
    counts = Counter([l[1] for l in lines])


new_lines = [l + [str(counts[l[1])] for l in lines]
with open(file_path_1, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header + ['Total_GeneralID'])
    writer.writerows(new_lines)

with open(file_path_1, 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        key_id.append(row['KeyID'])
        general_id.append(row['GeneralID'])
        total_general_id.append(['Total_GeneralID'])

New_List = [[] for _ in range(len(key_id))]
for attr in range(len(key_id)):
    New_List[attr].append(key_id[attr])
    New_List[attr].append(general_id[attr])
    New_List[attr].append(total_general_id[attr])

with open('result_id_with_total.csv', 'wb+') as newfile:
    header = ['KEY ID', 'GENERAL ID' , 'TOTAL GENERAL ID']
    wr = csv.writer(newfile, delimiter=',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    wr.writerow(header) #I already add the headers but it won't work. 
    for item in New_List:
        if item not in newfile:
            wr.writerow(item)
```

Unfortunately, my output would be like this(result_id_with_total.csv);

```
145258,KL456,2
145259,BG486,1
145260,HJ789,1
145261,KL456,2
```

What I am trying to achieve;

```
KEY ID,GENERAL ID,TOTAL GENERAL ID 
145258,KL456,2
145259,BG486,1
145260,HJ789,1
145261,KL456,2
```

My main problem in this code:

```
wr.writerow(header)
```

won't work.

Comment: besides this line needing to be: `new_lines = [l + [str(counts[l[1]])] for l in lines]`, what is wrong?  It runs for me.

Comment: @StephenRauch Your code worked well, this is another problematic, since you solved my problem last time so I inform you hoping that maybe you could see what's wrong. The output of this code gave me the data without headers..

Comment: What is `if item not in newfile:` trying to do?

Comment: @StephenRauch To remove duplicates in the original csv file. (write the data if it is not written yet in the newfile)

Comment: That will not work like that.  That compares a row to a file handle.  Not to the contents of the file.  To do that you will need to read in the entire file and the compare or merge the new data into the old data.

Comment: @StephenRauch I removed it and add this code to remove duplicates.

`seen = set()`
`for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_path_1, inplace=1):`
    `if line in seen: continue`
    `seen.add(line)`
   `print line,`

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with opening a file with `wb+` (write bytes). Because when you write a file in bytes mode you need to pass to it an array of bytes and not strings.

I get this error in the console when I run it:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Try changing `wb+` to just `w`, this does the trick.

```
with open('result_id_with_total.csv', 'w') as newfile:
    header = ['KEY ID', 'GENERAL ID' , 'TOTAL GENERAL ID']
    wr = csv.writer(newfile, delimiter=',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Comment: When I try to use w instead of w+, it gave me an error `IOError : File not open for reading` , but if I use the w+, I went back to my initial problem, data but no headers in csv output.